# Does it makes sense to use free() for a pointer who is already NULL?

Tags: c, pointers

I have one pointer which is `NULL`, but if `NULL` is its value, I think that is still all right to free the memory allocated for it.

Is this true?

Comment: No operation is performed.

Comment: It is legal and can make sense. If you initialise data properly you can `free(.)` pointers that may be `NULL`. If you recycle objects you may need to re-initialise them. `free(p); p=NULL;` is a common practice.